# What is a command you can run from CMD.exe that requires UAC elevation?

Tags: command-line, uac

I googled this, and I couldn't find an answer. What's a command that you have to UAC elevation in cmd.exe to run?

Comment: One of many examples would be `ipconfig /all`

Comment: Related: [Check if current Command Prompt was launched as the Administrator](http://superuser.com/q/667607/354511).

Comment: "net file" is a good one, because it doesn't require trying to change settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several commands that can't be performed unless you're running in an elevated command prompt. For example, setting a network adapter to DHCP:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

However, this will never *invoke* the UAC elevation dialog. You'll simply be notified that the command *requires* elevation:

```
C:\Users\Oliver>netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).
```

Comment: Using a command that makes a permanent and system-wide change just to check something is a recipe for disaster: you can never predict and/or eliminate all the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Another would be `REG ADD` to a registry key that you don’t have modify access to; e.g., anything (most things?) in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM).